# How to search column in the tables in a database for a specific text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

how to find a table based on some data? i have donzens of tbles in my db and i need a way to find a table by passing the data, how would i achieve that?

using sql server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Search all columns in all the tables in a database for a specific value](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#2)

Comment: it search for date? i want to search for any text

Comment: did you read the whole thing? there are 3 functions `FindMyData_String`, `FindMyData_Date` and `FindMyData_Number`

Comment: Even if there weren't... change the relevant data types. The approach is the same.

Comment: yea when i click the link it went to findmydata_date but i did not realized that it has 3 functions. - thanks for the link.